Does IEEE allow the use of BibTeX in the IEEE conference template?
I’m using the IEEE conference template here and plan to submit it to IEEE. I want to use BibTeX because it’s easy to generate and automatically sort references. However, I’m wondering if it’s actually acceptable to use. Is it okay to use BibTeX? Will it generate accurate references?

\section*{References}
Please number citations consecutively within brackets \cite{b1}. The
sentence punctuation follows the bracket \cite{b2}. Refer simply to
the reference  number, as in \cite{b3}---do not use Ref. \cite{b3}'' or reference \cite{b3}'' except at  the beginning of a sentence:
``Reference \cite{b3} was the first $\ldots$''
Number footnotes separately in superscripts. Place the actual footnote
at  the bottom of the column in which it was cited. Do not put
footnotes in the  abstract or reference list. Use letters for table
footnotes.
Unless there are six authors or more give all authors' names; do not
use  et al.''. Papers that have not been published, even if they have been  submitted for publication, should be cited as unpublished'' \cite{b4}. Papers  that have been accepted for
publication should be cited as ``in press'' \cite{b5}.  Capitalize
only the first word in a paper title, except for proper nouns and
element symbols.
For papers published in translation journals, please give the English
citation first, followed by the original foreign-language citation
\cite{b6}.

\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{b1} G. Eason, B. Noble, and I. N. Sneddon, ``On certain integrals of Lipschitz-Hankel type involving products of Bessel functions,'' Phil. Trans. Roy. Soc. London, vol. A247, pp. 529--551, April 1955.
\bibitem{b2} J. Clerk Maxwell, A Treatise on Electricity and Magnetism, 3rd ed., vol. 2. Oxford: Clarendon, 1892, pp.68--73.
\bibitem{b3} I. S. Jacobs and C. P. Bean, ``Fine particles, thin films and exchange anisotropy,'' in Magnetism, vol. III, G. T. Rado and H. Suhl, Eds. New York: Academic, 1963, pp. 271--350.
\bibitem{b4} K. Elissa, ``Title of paper if known,'' unpublished.
\bibitem{b5} R. Nicole, ``Title of paper with only first word capitalized,'' J. Name Stand. Abbrev., in press.
\bibitem{b6} Y. Yorozu, M. Hirano, K. Oka, and Y. Tagawa, ``Electron spectroscopy studies on magneto-optical media and plastic substrate interface,'' IEEE Transl. J. Magn. Japan, vol. 2, pp. 740--741, August 1987 [Digests 9th Annual Conf. Magnetics Japan, p. 301, 1982].
\bibitem{b7} M. Young, The Technical Writer's Handbook. Mill Valley, CA: University Science, 1989.
\end{thebibliography}


Well, the template loads the cite citation management package. Plus, it defines a macro called \BibTeX. This only makes sense if you're allowed to employ BibTeX to generate the bibliography with numeric-style citation call-outs. If you use the IEEEtran bibliography style, you'll be fine.
